# Detect duplicate and update instead of create with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to use a callback to check accepts_nested_attributes_for params for any duplicate records and update instead of create when conditions are met.

Is this possible?

What I have tried:

```
before_validation :update_instead

  def update_instead
    unless self.id
      existing_provision = Provision.where(survey_id: self.survey_id).where(service_id: self.service_id).first
      if existing_provision
        self.id = existing_provision.id
      end  
    end
  end
```

This doesn't work as it just tries to create a record with the id set, which obviously triggers an error with duplicate id.

Comment: and this is where requirements start making you write complex logic(hidden stuff, more magic, etc). Is this a requirement from your managers ?. Why would you do that ?, you need the ID to identify if it's an update, if it's there then it's a new record, unless you change your ID to be `survey_id` and `service_id`.

Comment: May be it's better just not to create new `Provision` with the same `survey_id` and `service_id`? Changing `id` is very strange idea

Comment: @fanta No, I'm asking how to do what is described above, not if it isn't required or not, that would take a larger look at the whole feature, which is beyond SO.

Comment: @mechnicov - Not changing the id.  I'm detecting if its a duplicate and updating instead of creating.

Comment: ok, fair enough. I'll tell you something about nested attributes and forms for nested attributes, I personally don't like to use that approach. What I'd do is use the the Form Object pattern, for reference look at https://thoughtbot.com/blog/activemodel-form-objects and https://medium.com/selleo/essential-rubyonrails-patterns-form-objects-b199aada6ec9. And write your logic there, you'd have to loop through the nested resources and see if they exist.

Comment: ok, thanks.  ill take a look

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you can use `find_or_create_by` for this purpose

```
provision = Provision.find_or_create_by(survey_id: self.survey_id, service_id: self.service_id)
provision.update(foo: bar)
```